# JSF format an h:inputText while typing

Tags: jsf, string-formatting

I'm constructing a page with pure JSF.

On that page I've some field for dates... but I don't need a date picker. So I used an `<h:inputText>`

This is working when I type a valid date like 01/01/1970. But I need to type the "/".

I want to put some mask on this input. How can I do that?

Comment: With some Javascript. You can't do it in pure JSF. It only renders an html:input element.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use jQuery or a JSF component library like Primefaces.

With [Primefaces inputMask](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputMask.xhtml), you can do this

```
<p:inputMask id="date" value="#{maskView.date}" mask="99/99/9999"/>
```

Alternatively, if using jQuery, the [jQuery Mask plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/mask/) provides similar functionality. It is used by simply locating the input element, then applying the mask() javascript function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
});
```

If Primefaces and jQuery are not options, plain Javascript can always be used. A bit of warning thought, using plain JS for this will require a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with plain JS...

Added `<f:ajax event="keypress" onevent="formatDate(this)"/>` on inputText

and the function

```
function formatarData(obj) {
    if (obj.value.length == 2 || obj.value.length == 5) {
        obj.value += "/";
    }
    return;
}
```